# I have a question on how to prove an inequality holds true.

Tags: calculus, inequality

How do I prove that for $a < b< c$ and $n \geq 3$ then the inequality $$b^n+c^n > a^n$$ holds true.

I tried setting $c =b+n$ but I don't know we're to go from here !

Comment: I think you need also that $0<a$.

Comment: Do you want $0<a<b<c$? Otherwise you can have something like $-2<-1<0$, but $1=(-1)^4+0^4<(-2)^4=16$

Comment: Why are you using the same $n$ for the power and $c-b$?

Comment: Hint: Can you prove $b^n>a^n$ and that $c^n>0$?

Comment: I can  b > a so lnb>lna so nlnb > nlnb therfore 2 more steps we get $b^n$ > $a^n$.  $c^n$ will be always postive if c>0. However I was looking for a proof for all a,b,c. Thanks to all who disproved this inequality.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
(assuming the numbers are positive)

Use the fact that $$x > y > 0 \implies x^n > y^n$$ and $$x > y, z > 0 \implies x+z > y$$